# Custom Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get custom routes based on the username rather than the ID. I have it working to get to the show page of the user but I am also trying to nest the resources so that I can see his posts and comments using the same syntax.

Example:

*Works...* "mysite.com/users/**username**/"

*Does not work...* "mysite.com/users/**username**/posts/"

routes.rb

```rb
...
# Users with the Username...
match 'users/:username' => "users#show" do
    get :posts
    get :comments
end

# Users with the ID...
resources :users do
    get :posts
    get :comments
end
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [to_param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param) method and update your nested routes/resources:

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts
    resources :comments
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
   username
  end
end
```

..for finds in the UserController:

```
 @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

(or any variation of finding by the username criteria)

Comment: I have seen this solution before. It seems like a hack and it overrides the built in find method and can lead to a bunch of errors. There must be a cleaner way to do this within rails 3.1.

Comment: This doesn't effect the model's find method in any way so I'm not sure what errors that could cause. Yes, you will have to change your criteria for the finds in the controller to find by the username, but I assume you are doing that anyway. This only overrides the object's to_param method which means params[:id] would now be the username.  It will also automatically build your routes using the username as well.  I'm not sure how it could get much cleaner actually. If you want to still use the numerical id from the params in the controller, that is a different story.